# Object Defined or Application Defined Error, Formula String

Tags: excel, excel-formula, string-concatenation, type-mismatch, vba

I seem to be having a type mismatch error in the below formula. `Numbering`, `Approval`, `PeakShare`, and `RampUp` are all stored as ranges, `app` as an integer. I believe I have escaped my quotes correctly in trying to include the value of 'app'. But I get a "Type mismatch" error in return. I have also tried including a non-variable integer and receive an "Object defined or application defined error." I have read some things about the use of indirect and approval in Excel formulas but haven't found much out there with its use in VBA, is this the problem?

```
formulaUp = "=IF(" & Numbering.Address(True, False) & "<" & Approval.Address &    ","""", " & PeakShare.Address & " * " & RampUp.Offset(0, -"" & app & "" + 1).Address(True, False) & ")"
```

Comment: the quotes are not needed here `RampUp.Offset(0, -"" & app & "" + 1)` just do `RampUp.Offset(0, - 1 * app  + 1)`

Comment: I'm still returning the application defined or object defined error as I was when passing a non-variable integer

Comment: And the code works as intended when I remove the `Offset(0, - 1 * app +1)`  portion @ScottCraner

Comment: Then `app -1` is greater than the column number of `RampUp` and you are trying move off the page.  When it stops, type `?RampUp.Address` in the immediate window and also `?app` and see if `app - 1` is greater than the column number.

Comment: Ahh thank you, that was the problem!

Answer (score 1):

The type mismatch comes from

```
RampUp.Offset(0, -"" & app & "" + 1)
```

The second argument you are trying to pass to `Offset` does not make much sense, and throws because according to operator precedence it's `(-"") & app & ("" + 1)`, and neither of the bracketed expressions can be calculated.

Apparently you meant

```
RampUp.Offset(0, -app + 1)
```

Comment: Thanks @GSerg , I had a feeling it was something wrong with my syntax which is why I passed a non-variable integer through. I'm still returning the object defined error as I mentioned above, any idea why including the `Offset(0, - 1 * app +1)` would cause this?